# .net web service as a client of java web service

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I have a .net 4.0 web app which needs to connect to a customer's web service, written in Java (it has cxf in the service endpoint)

Their service endpoint is https, and ultimately I will need to supply an x509 credential, but not yet.
They do not allow discovery, they dont expose a mex endpoint, they have supplied us with a wsdl and xsds, and I've managed to create a client proxy.

I'm struggling to set the right wcf client configuration. What I have so far is this: (names changed for obvious reasons).

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding name="CUSwsBinding"  />
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://customer.com/cxf/customerMaintenance/"
        binding="basicHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="CUSwsBinding"
        contract="CUSCustomer.Customerxxx" name="CUSCustomerWS" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

When I try and execute, it says the basicHttpBinding extension is not recognised. I see there are some bindings that only are supported in .net 4.5, however my manager has Fear, Uncertainty and Doubt, and our web app has to stay on 4.0
Not an expert in WCF, so any help welcome.

As someone suggested, one can create an instance of the proxy class:

```
var client = new proxy.ClientClass();
```

At this line it throws a Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/basicHttpsBinding' could not be found.
The endpointaddress needs to be in config, as its currently pointing at a test environment, will be poiting at production

Comment: This has nothing to do with WCF, you're just creating a client and i don't know why you're doing WCF client configuration

Comment: I'm not sure how else I can connect to the end point, obviously I dont want to start building soap messages, adding certificates in code when that can be done in config. (I'm not a fan of WCF, BTW - I think they simply moved the complexity out of the code, where we can debug, into config, which we cant)

Comment: just add your proxy class to your project, create an object of your class and you can add your certificate from code as easily as possible , a console app will do the job

Comment: The client proxy that is created by the tool  needs some configuration. First and foremost, an endpoint address: 
    var client=new proxy.ClientClass(); 
    client.Endpoint.address=new EndpointAddress(https:/// etc etc);
    client.CallMethod() -- at this line it throws a configuration exception.
One way or anothe I need to give it the config - it seems easiest to use the built-in schema

Comment: I have already worked with java web services using only wsdl+xsd and .NET , if you look into the WSDL file you'll find the endpoint address of the service , you're just creating a client application

Comment: Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/basicHttpsBinding' could not be found

Comment: Following SO guidelines, I'll add some comments to the orginal post.